# What to do if a company with bad reputation provides a job?

Tags: job-offer, finland

Is there any advice what one should do in the following situation? I am unemployed in Finland. In Finnish law, if one provides you a job and you decline it, you won't get an unemployment benefit. But now a company that provides a really small salary and has a bad reputation offers me a job via https://kokeile.tyomarkkinatori.fi/Etusivu . I hate to take the job but I'm not willing to live some months without any payment. The job is about selling a product in telephone and my education is on a complete different field.

Comment: Yeah yeah 0/-3 DVs, but I think it's an interesting question.  So +1/-3 now :)

Comment: Did you apply for this job?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about labor laws in Finland.

Comment: Why did you apply for the job?

Comment: @Kilisi Maybe it was offered by the employment agency. I do not know Finnish laws, but in Europe there are countries that can force you to take certain jobs if they cannot find employment for you otherwise.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs or it could be a random person offering a job via email, or aliens, hence why I asked the question.

Comment: I got the message from the web site työmarkkinatori that is held by the unemloyment agency if I have understood correctly. Therefore I am afraid to lose my unemployment benefit if I refuse the job.

Comment: @O.Jones is that off-topic? I see a lot of questions that are basically about labor laws of a specific country

Comment: Is it even a question about law? I think this is an on-topic question about accepting what you are given and making the most of the options at hand.

Comment: Why is this offtopic? (I am not the question author)

Comment: This is a valid question and should be reopened.  If the location was the USA rather than Finland, it would not have been closed

Comment: Voting to close this as Opinion based. We can´t tell you what to do.

Comment: This is on the edge of being off-topic and perhaps better suited to [money.se] but I think it's within bounds here. For example it would also be good for hiring managers to know whether a candidate they extend an offer to might be accepting it for legal reasons rather than because they're excited about the job.

Comment: @Lilienthal is has no clear goal and is basically asking us what to to. The answer could only be take the job, but keep looking or reject the job and start living on your savings. How is that useful for anyone?

Comment: That said, @guest, could you [edit] your question to remove that link and just clarify what that means? Not sure if your question is "Do  I need to accept any offer I get?" or "Does an email via Website X constitute a valid job offer?".

Comment: @Daniel Messages crossed, but the comment I just posted has two version of the question that I consider answerable. It's more technical / fact-driven than most of our question but this is usually considered on-topic here. We just don't get too many questions from the Nordics I suppose. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should look up if they can actually force you to work at that company. In my country, which has a welfare state that is comparable to the Finnish welfare state, you can't forced into a field if you have a different education and you generally don't have any experience in that kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

So, let us clarify the question.  Assuming that you are correct on the matter of law, you have three options.

The first is to work for little pay, at a company with a bad reputation, doing something that's not in your field.  Further, it's a job that's generally quite emotionally draining.  (You spend your day calling up people who don't want to be called, and trying to convincing them to spend money on something that they generally won't want or need.  People will react poorly to this.  It is likely to be emotionally draining for you.)  The issue here is that it's a lousy experience, not much money, and it'll make it harder for you to gather together the resources to find a real job.

The second is to accept that this company, by their offer, has deprived you of unemployment benefits, and push as hard as you can on trying to find a real job that is in your field as fast as possible, in the hopes of getting said real job before your money runs out.  The obvious issue here is that you won't be getting *any* income in the meantime.  If it takes too long for you to get a job, and you don't have the cash reserves to support it, you could be in real trouble.  This one's going to depend on how bad the job market for your type is where you are, and how much money you have available in your emergency fund to cover situations like this.

The third is to try to split the difference.  Being underpaid by a bad company to make sales calls is rough work, emotionally speaking.  Is *anyone* hiring where you are?  Is there an accessible gig economy?  Is the military recruiting?  Your situation has just been made materially worse, and you need to re-evaluate your available options.  You may not be able to get the kind of job you *want* fast enough to handle your bills without unemployment, but there's a good chance that there's something out there that you could grab that would be better than the job you were offered.  The issue here is that it splits the difference between the other options.  On the one side, it might still take some times to get employed - you don't have an offer in hand right now.  On the other side, once you do get hired, it won't be as good as the job you want, and you'll probably have to keep looking.

So, first, be sure that you're understanding the law correctly.  If you are?  You have three options to consider, all bad.  Discard the ones you simply cannot accept, and see if there are any left.  If not, lower your standards, and do it again.  Pick the option that is least bad for your particular situation.

Comment: My experience with telemarketing company is they hire quick and fire quick if you don´t make the required sales. So OP could be out of this job pretty quickly how this affects his unemployment is another interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

**Under this system, what happens if you can't do the job?**

This mandatory employment strategy is going to lead to many people being matched to work they cannot actually do. What happens to people who cannot actually do the job assigned? Do you get your unemployment benefits back if you are terminated for a lack of relevant skill?

If you can get them back, show up, accept that you will probably fail (as that is what happens to most people who try telemarketing), fail, and then get back to the rest of your life. You never need to list this job on your resume either.

Comment: This is what most people actually do, if they don't want any job at all. Sometimes they accept the offer officially and never show up until they get fired.